# How do I push a field of an object into another array of object

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, object, ecmascript-6

I know how to operate on array of objects but never had the necessity to populate an array data into another. I need to populate firstname + lastname field into name field of birth array

```
let birth = [
    {name: '' }
]
```

firstly my array is empty and i want to poplulate it with these datas

```
let names = [
   {firstname: "Julien", lastname: "DEHAIS"},
   {firstname: "Cyril", lastname: "GUIGUIAN"},
   {firstname: "Pascal", lastname: "BOUTRIN"},
   {firstname: "Franck", lastname: "BORDERIE"},
   {firstname: "Arnold", lastname: "GIRARD"}
]
```

to get something like this

```
let birth = [
    {name: 'Julien DEHAIS' },
    {name: 'Cyril GUIGUIAN' },
    {name: 'Pascal BOUTRIN' },
    {name: 'Franck BORDERIE' },
    {name: 'Arnold GIRARD' }
]
```

Kindly someone help me in this please

Comment: And what have you tried so far?

Comment: It's a very simple `Array.map()` that just adds the first- and last name together inside a new object.

Comment: @JonasWilms How does that answer the question? The OP doesn't want the values, they want a new array of objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple `map`:

```js
let names = [{firstname:"Julien",lastname:"DEHAIS"},{firstname:"Cyril",lastname:"GUIGUIAN"},{firstname:"Pascal",lastname:"BOUTRIN"},{firstname:"Franck",lastname:"BORDERIE"},{firstname:"Arnold",lastname:"GIRARD"}];
const res = names.map(({ firstname, lastname }) => ({ name: firstname + " " + lastname }));
console.log(res);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: auto; }
```

ES5 syntax:

```js
var names = [{firstname:"Julien",lastname:"DEHAIS"},{firstname:"Cyril",lastname:"GUIGUIAN"},{firstname:"Pascal",lastname:"BOUTRIN"},{firstname:"Franck",lastname:"BORDERIE"},{firstname:"Arnold",lastname:"GIRARD"}];
var res = names.map(function(e) {
  return { name: e.firstname + " " + e.lastname };
});
console.log(res);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: auto; }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `map()` and return a new object with `name` property

```js
let names = [ {firstname: "Julien", lastname: "DEHAIS"}, {firstname: "Cyril", lastname: "GUIGUIAN"}, {firstname: "Pascal", lastname: "BOUTRIN"}, {firstname: "Franck", lastname: "BORDERIE"}, {firstname: "Arnold", lastname: "GIRARD"} ]

const res = names.map(x => ({name: `${x.firstname} ${x.lastname}`}))
console.log(res)
```

Comment: JavaScript objects are *unordered* - the second one is very unreliable (what if the values get swapped? `DEHAIS Julien`)